# How do I round a number in JSTL?

Tags: math, jsp, jstl, el, rounding

I'm doing a division in a JSP and I'd like to round the result - how should I do this?

i.e.

```
<c:set
  var="expiry"
  value="${(expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000)}"/>
```

...how do I round the result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="expiry"
  value="${(expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000)}"
  maxFractionDigits="0" />
```

This way you do not lose localization (commas and dots).

Comment: I'd agree with this answer.  JSTL should not be concerned with "properly" implementing any logic like rounding.  That's a middle tier decision.  JSP and JSTL should only be for display.  The format tag is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 10):

I used:

```
${fn:substringBefore(expiry, '.')}
```

which truncates rather than rounding, but that may be good enough.

Comment: Be careful, in some languages the decimal separator is the comma (e.g. Spanish)

Answer (score 2):

It may looks like:

```
<c:set var="expire" value="100"/>
<c:set var="now" value="3"/>

<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${(expire mod now)!=0}">
  <c:set var="res" value="${(expire - (expire mod now))/now}"/>
  ${res}
 </c:when>
 <c:otherwise>
  <c:set var="res" value="${expire/now}"/>
  ${res}
 </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

note: i think you should use **mod** anyway or **%** functionality of jstl,i use mod in example.
Test,please, "expire" and "now" variables with different values, should work ok.

Answer (score 1):

What about this dirty hack:

```
<c:set
  var="expiry"
  value="${(((expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000) * 100) - 0.5) / 100.0}"/>
```

But I would do this in a bean and just show the result here. Beside this, you can [define functions in your tld](http://faq.javaranch.com/java/DefineELFunctions) or, if that is not supported in your environment get functions in the expression language by implementing a Map and (ab)use it. You implement the get(Object) method to do what you want and call it like this:

```
<c:set
  var="expiry"
  value="${Helpers.round[(expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000)]"/>
```

Note, Helpers provides a "getRound()" method which returns your Map implementation.

Answer (score 1):

With the current EL version you can use

```
<c:set var="expiry"
value="${Math.round( (expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000) )}"/>
```

or

```
<c:set var="expiry"
value="${Math.floor( (expire.time - now.time) / (60 * 1000) )}"/>
```