# Browse 2D array columns in JSTL

Tags: java, arrays

I have this little issue that is cracking my skull :( I have a 2D Array in my class, I send it by request to my jsp page and I have to iterate through it BUT by columns! I know I can do

```
    <c:forEach items="${board.cells}" var="row">
     <tr>
       <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
        <td><c:out value="${cell}"/></td>
       </c:forEach>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

And iterate by rows, but I can't find a way I can do that but by columns. I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do and can help me. Greetins from Colombia and thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846812/how-to-write-out-an-array-of-objects-in-columns-using-jstl

Comment: Maybe if I had the number of rows I'm going to send :/

Answer (score 0):

you can pass from controller only the array for exemple:

```
addModu..("board",array[][]); // exemple pass only array
```

now you can try this :

```
  <c:forEach items="${board}" var="row">
     <tr>
       <c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
        <td><c:out value="${cell}"/></td>
       </c:forEach>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

as you already you're passing the array, forEach iterate for each position on array

I think your problem is how to pass the parameter...

Good Lucky

Comment: I made a workaround by sending a single array with every column as an array in each position, so it "looks" like a 2D array but it's way easier to iterate over it. Not the best solution but it worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: vale manoPajaro jajaja en español te lo podria haber explicado mejor xD