# To use expression language to get values

Tags: spring, spring-expression-language, spring-expression

My expression is :`#age*10`  And I assigned a value of 15.6 to age
The result of this is `156.0`   In fact the final result I want to get is：`156`

I can do it in the code, but how to do it by modifying the expression.

thanks

Comment: Maybe this is related to: [How do I round a number in JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1443528/344480)

Comment: You've just mentioned `expression` in the tag but it's not clear whether it's `JSTL` or `SpEL` or something else. Tag it properly to get the right attention.

Comment: It should be SPEL expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Integer.class` as shown below:

```
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        Double age = 15.6;
        context.setVariable("age", age);
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#age*10");
        int result = exp.getValue(context, Integer.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
156
```

Comment: thank you .I will use this method to adapt the data